# Getting Child window reference from parent after parent is refreshed

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11

Here is the scenario:

1. I'm in parent window. I click on a link, which opens a child window
2. Now I'm in child window, I enter some data and click on a submit button
3. Now, the child window refreshes. After the child window completes refreshing, the parent window refreshes.
4. After the parent window refreshes, the child window goes background, which I don't want. I want that to remain foreground.

NOW, I searched how to get the reference of child window from the parent window and found this link-
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25388/Accessing-parent-window-from-child-window-or-vice#b

My question is - Will I be able to successfully get the reference of the child window **even after the parent window has refreshed**?

**More info:** This happens only in IE and not in Chrome/Firefox.

**UPDATE:** As per this link - https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/48485/parentchild-windows-references
The parent will not have control over child anymore. But is there a way I can maintain the focus on the child window even after the parent window refreshes?

Comment: Im not 100% sure of the question but maybe try iFrames? Create a new page on the same server location with the contents of that small window. And then try and test the submit from within that window and see if it doesnt refresh everything. Then that should allow you to not only submit the data, but keep access to the small window without total refresh

Comment: somdow is right. iFrame should solve your problem. it can have its own viewstate